# Block the facebook user thumbnail link inside spotify

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed, spotify

I'm working on an app inside spotify, and I want users to share content with each other.

What I've done is use spotifys showAuthenticationDialog with and url looking something like
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=< appid >&to=< otheruser >&link=< link >&redirect_uri=< redirect >&display=popup

*I would have posted an image showing the dialog here... but didn't have enough reputation on stackoverflow ;)*

Now the problem is that clicking the users thumbnail will display that users facebook page inside the popup. Is there any way to block this?

Facebooks example works the same way, but I've seen other applications/games on facebook that has managed to block this link.

Thanks in advance!

Roger

Comment: Are you sure they're definitely 'blocking' this, and not rendering their own interface and then making the post directly to the /feed connection?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but take songpop for instance, if you challange a friend and after playing your turn, this dialog shows. Using chrome and checking the source, I can see the link is still there, though nothing happens when I click. But songpop isn't the best reference since it's not run in spotify.

Answer (score 0):

If it's doing it inside a popup window you don't control inside the Spotify client, that's a bug in Spotify.